# Windows static site generator

Tags: windows, static-site-generator

In the past, I've used laravel, which had the blade templateing engine. It was beautiful. It was simple. It made my life so much easier.

Now for my current employer, I'm manually updating 20+ with identical header and footers. Keeping them all the same is a major pain, any minor change has to be copied across all 20 pages. Our server isn't complex enough to do anything like server-side page assembly, and honestly, we don't really need it, all I'd like is a dev-side app that takes keywords, something like

```
template file

<!--Header content goes here-->
@yield('page content')
<!--Footer Content goes here-->
```

and then

```
content file

@section('page content')
<!--Main page content goes here-->
@endsection
```

where the second files content is inserted into the first file. If it exists, I would preferrably need something that compiles a whole project into a folder of static html files. The secondary hitch is that it has to work on windows. While I'm familiar with linux, I need to leave it in a state that any possible replacement could pick it up without to much hassle, and unfortunately, for this company, that precludes linux.